# Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties Swift Xcode 10.0

Tags: swift

All the variable in my structure are optional then also in constructor I am getting this issue?
"Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"

```
struct Conversation : Codable {


    let chat_id : String?
    let id : String?
    let name : String?
    let profile_pic : String?
    let last_message_from : String?
    let message : String?
    let time : String?
    let unread_count : String?
    let member_count : String?
    var type : ChatType = .Single
    var doctors:[Doctors]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case chat_id = "chat_id"
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case profile_pic = "profile_pic"
        case last_message_from = "last_message_from"
        case message = "message"
        case time = "time"
        case unread_count = "unread_count"
        case member_count = "member_count"
        case doctors = "doctors"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        chat_id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .chat_id)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        profile_pic = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .profile_pic)
        last_message_from = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .last_message_from)
        message = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
        time = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .time)
        unread_count = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .unread_count)
        member_count = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .member_count)
        doctors = try values.decodeIfPresent([Doctors].self, forKey: .doctors)
    }



    init(doctor:Doctors) {
        self.id = doctor.doctorId
        self.profile_pic = doctor.doctorPic
        self.type = .Single
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an initializer, you need to specify the value for all stored properties in the initializer, you cannot use the default values of your properties. So even if you declare your properties as `Optional`, you need to assign `nil` value to them in your initializer if you want them to be `nil`.

Unrelated to your issue, but there's no need to declare `CodingKeys` if all of your property names match your JSON keys and there's also no need to manually write the `init(from:)` initializer, the compiler can automatically synthesise that for you in your simple case. However, you should conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names (including `enum` cases), so rename your properties accordingly and then you'll need `CodingKeys`.

Be aware that a lot of your types don't actually make sense. Why are the variables called `count` `String`s? If they're coming as `String`s from the backend, convert them to `Int`s in `init(from:)`. Also, in your `init(doctor:)` it would make sense to actually add `doctor` to your `doctors` array.

```
struct Conversation : Codable {

    let chatId: String?
    let id: String?
    let name: String?
    let profilePic: String?
    let lastMessageFrom: String?
    let message: String?
    let time: String?
    let unreadCount: String?
    let memberCount: String?
    var type: ChatType = .single
    var doctors:[Doctors]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case chatId = "chat_id"
        case id
        case name
        case profilePic = "profile_pic"
        case lastMessageFrom = "last_message_from"
        case message
        case time
        case unreadCount = "unread_count"
        case memberCount = "member_count"
        case doctors
    }

    init(doctor:Doctors) {
        self.id = doctor.doctorId
        self.profilePic = doctor.doctorPic
        self.type = .single
        self.chatId = nil
        self.name = nil
        self.lastMessageFrom = nil
        self.message = nil
        self.time = nil
        self.unreadCount = nil
        self.memberCount = nil
        self.doctors = [doctor]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , nice explanation.

Comment: for sure answer is accepted but since variables are optional in nature so in that case no need to assign specifically to stored properties,  just a clean in this case resolved my issue.